# Django: Tweepy API not Working

Tags: python, django

I’m trying to view the list of members in my twitter list through Tweepy. When I try to visit the page in my django app, I’m getting the below error. But when I try to check through shell terminal (manage.py shell) it will display the members in my list.

How can I solve this?

```
       TweepError at /list/
       [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
       Request Method:  GET
       Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/
       Django Version:  1.4
       Exception Type:  TweepError
       Exception Value: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
       Exception Location:  build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\binder.py in execute, line 168
       Python Executable:   C:\Python27\python.exe
       Python Version:  2.7.3
       Python Path: ['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\crack',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_social_auth-0.6.9-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tweepy-1.9-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_imagekit-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
                     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
                     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
                     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
         Server time:   Wed, 30 May 2012 10:07:07 +0100
```

Views

```
        def listmem(request):
            Users= api.list_members(owner=request.user, slug='map')
            for User in Users:
                print User
            return render_to_response('listmember.html',{'Users': Users},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
          {% block content %}
             {% for User in Users %} 

                 <p> <img src={{ User.profile_image_url }} /> {{ User.screen_name}}<a>   </p> 
          {% endfor %} 

           {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that owner (taken from `request.user`) and the slug are correct?

The Twitter response is telling you that the resource (list in this case) is not found, so one of these is incorrect.

Comment: Other possibilities: authenticated vs. not authenticated (important for private lists), and, still, request.user is not the type you are expecting.

Comment: that views work when I'm using django 1.3. After updating to 1.4 I start getting this error. Don't know what to do for now.

Comment: Interesting. So either Django 1.4 provides you with a different value for request.user (one that tweepy doesn't know how to handle), or Django messes with the stdlib `httplib` library in such a way that tweepy fails.

Comment: Also, quick debug idea: replace `request.user` with a static string and see if that works.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that, when I create a list through shell terminal with tweepy, it will return an object showing that it has created and when I try to visit twitter.com on my browser to check, I will found out that it didn't create anything. So I decided to create it manually and check the timeline through shell terminal and I'm getting the above error. I guess something is wrong with tweepy!

Comment: I tried it with another twitter account, it's now working! But why is it not working with the rest?